# What were some Mexican contributions to high school level algebra and statistics?

Tags: math-history

I want to do a presentation on Mexican mathematicians' contribution to either high school level algebra or statistics. What kind of resources are out there? Does anyone know of a contribution that I can write about? I checked online and there didn't seem to be anything available.

Comment: You will have to research, but http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Mexican_mathematicians, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Spanish_mathematicians, http://www.ask.com/question/names-of-famous-hispanic-mathematicians, http://www.matedu.cinvestav.mx/~asacristan/NationalPresentationPME32.pdf